# Writing the sout statement outside of the loop in java

Tags: java, loops, printing, scope, boolean

```java
public static boolean isStrongNumber(int x){
    for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
        factorial(i);
        if (i == factorial(i)) {
            System.out.println("The strong numbers between 1 and " + x + " are: " + factorial(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Regardless of what was before, I just want to know to print the `sout` statement only once with the looped values of `factorial(i)` knowing that if I put it outside the for loop, it won't know what variable `i` is due to the scope variable rule.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve here. What is `factorial()` ? You don't have to declare `i` inside the `for`, you can declare it outside if that's what you're asking.

Comment: i solved it, i put System.out.print("The strong numbers between 1 and "+x+" are: ") before the for loop and then the i changed the existed sout to factorial(i)+" "